# Decrypting Always Encrypted Column ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I've encrypted a couple of columns in a SQL database hosted in Azure. I did the encryption (deterministic) using AzureKeyVault. I've given the App Service in Azure itself access to the KeyVault. I've also added the `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` to the connection string. I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 for my data layer.

However when I run a query against a table that has the encryption, I simply receive a timeout error.

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I've looked at adding this code and calling it in my `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method:

```
public class AzureKeyValueConfiguration
{
    private static ClientCredential _clientCredential;

    public static void InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider()
    {
        string clientId = "MyClient";
        string clientSecret = "MySecret";
        _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

        Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers =
            new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();

        providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);
        SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
    }

    private async static Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _clientCredential);

        if (result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the access token");

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        AzureKeyValueConfiguration.InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider();
}
```

However, I'm not even sure if this code is firing as I can't get it to hit in the debugger.  All in all, I'm a bit lost and could use some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the query, that you are running. It could be that your query fetches all the encrypted data to decrypt it and that's why it takes so long.

Comment: Hi, my query is like this: entity = db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.AccountId == id);

Comment: This isn't the query, that is ran in the database :) Is AccountId encrypted? Just capture the T-SQL query, which is executed in the database by this linq query and post it here.

Comment: Ok after a lot of digging (EF sure hides the erorr messages) I found out it was because my App Service didn't have the 'Verify' permission to the Azure Key vault.  Now, I can read the data fine... however I cannot update the data now.  Thanks for helping.